# Parts inside a LCD 16x02

Tags: lcd

This picture is from an application note from Microchip about LCDs.
I just disassembled a common 16x02 LCD and I want to identify the components shown in the Microchip's figure with the ones from my LCD. Can you help me to figure out how it works ?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your one has a backlight,  unlike the reflective or transmissive type shown in the Microchip data. The white and transparent plastic bits are diffusers for the backlight LEDs.

All the rest is bonded together in the glass part to the left.

There are no pins on your display, the connections to the Indium-tin-oxide (ITO) terminals on the glass are made with little elastomer strips that have alternating conductive and insulating layers. Presumably out of the photo.

Comment: but where is the LC fluid that gets polarised ?

Comment: The fluid is sealed between the two sheets of glass that are bonded together into that assembly on the left. Look at the edge of the glass part end-on, preferably with a microscope or magnifier.

Comment: now I understand the purpose of those pink elastomers and how the LC gets polarised. Thank you very much !!!!

Comment: also a 16X2 character display will have a passive matrix instead of individual segment electrodes.